# AFNetworking POST get 403 forbidden, but Curl works

Tags: afnetworking

I want to use AFNetworking to POST to sinatra project to get json data. AFNetwroking always get back 403 status code. But curl works as expect. Why?

Here is the error on Xcode:

```
<AFHTTPRequestOperation: 0x7ffd5da42780, state: isFinished, cancelled: NO request: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7ffd5d9591b0> { URL: http://127.0.0.1:9292/api/v1/events/new }, response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ffd5b7b7030> { URL: http://127.0.0.1:9292/api/v1/events/new } { status code: 403, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 69;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 23 Jan 2015 08:42:32 GMT";
    Server = "WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.5/2014-11-13)";
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
} }>
```

Curl on terminal:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9292/api/v1/events/new 
{"error_code":10001,"error_message":"need token or token is illegal"}%
```

IOS code doesn't work:

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:9292/"]];
    [manager POST:@"api/v1/events/new" 
    parameters:nil 
    success:nil 
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {DLog(@"%@",operation);}];
```

rackup log:

```
[2015-01-23 16:58:20] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-01-23 16:58:20] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
[2015-01-23 16:58:20] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=14445 port=9292
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jan/2015:16:58:36 +0800] "POST /api/v1/events/new HTTP/1.1" 403 69 0.0179
```

Comment: Have you tried to change it to GET method? curl for post requires --data or  -X POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works right, my server side make a path filter, but here provide a way, sometime not only just print `operation` but also `operation.responseObject` which i got what i want.

```
{
    "error_code" = 10001;
    "error_message" = "need token or token is illegal";
}
```